# Using inner joins and aliases in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to join several different values from the same table. I'm trying to return printing rates in the query from different time horizons (how much has been printed in the month/day/year/week etc.) and I am getting a 1064 error when I execute the query below. What could the explanation be?

```
SELECT t1.station_name, t1.yearpages, t2.monthpages
FROM (
    SELECT station_name, SUM(print_pages) yearpages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE year(print_date) = 2014;
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT station_name, sum(print_pages) monthpages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE month(print_date) = 2;
) ON t1.station_name = t2.station_name;
```

Then, if I were to add multiple joins, would the query look like this?

```
SELECT t1.station_name, t1.station_name as db_name, t1.yearpages, t2.monthpages, t3.daypages, t4.weekpages
FROM (
    SELECT station_name, sum(print_pages) yearpages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE year(print_date) = $year;
    GROUP BY station_name
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT station_name, sum(print_pages) monthpages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE month(print_date) = $month;
    GROUP BY station_name
) t2 ON t1.station_name = t2.station_name 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT station_name, sum(print_pages) daypages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE dayofmonth(print_date) = $day;
    GROUP BY station_name
) t3 ON t2.station_name = t3.station_name
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT station_name, sum(print_pages) weekpages
    FROM `file_prints`
    WHERE week(print_date) = $week;
    GROUP BY station_name
) t4 ON t3.station_name = t4.station_name
```

Comment: Your first query has a semicolon in the middle of it -- as does your second query.  This is probably the cause of your errors.

Comment: `WHERE month(print_date) = 2;` remove semicolon at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT station_name,
       sum(case when year(print_date) = $year then print_pages end) as yearpages,
       sum(case when month(print_date) = $month then print_pages end) as monthpages,
       sum(case when day(print_date) = $day then print_pages end) as daypages,
       sum(case when week(print_date) = $week then print_pages end) as weekpages
FROM `file_prints`
GROUP BY station_name;
```